# In php script code document.createElement('p').textContent is not null or something like that, but it won't display the created element. Why?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm new in php programming. I'm in a very interesting moment.

```
let str = 'anytext';
line = document.createElement('p');
line.textContent = str;
               
alert('line = ' + line.textContent);
```

I tried to use and .textContent and .innerHTML and .innerText. Nothing. It refuses to display anything.

The alert shows that the value successfully assigned. No errors, but there is nothing displayed on
the screen of the browser. I mean, no paragraph element created visually.

I use javascript not in html document. I use it in php file.
The page has a table, which I created programmatically with php.

I thought I can solve this problem by sending the

```
$html = new DOMDocument('1.0','iso-8859-1');
```

with json_encode() and JSON.parse(); to javascript. But it didn't help too.

I don't know what else can I do. Can you help me?

Comment: you need to append the element somewhere after you create it, e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append

Comment: This doesn't appear to have anything to do with PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've *created* an element, but you haven't *inserted* it anywhere into the document. You need to figure out the appropriate place to put it into the DOM and then do so.

For example, if you have existing HTML of

```
<div class="main">
</div>
```

you can create a `<p>` and insert it to the bottom of the `.main` with

```
const main = document.querySelector('.main');
const line = document.createElement('p');
line.textContent = 'anytext';
main.appendChild(line);
```

Comment: Ohhh... one minute. I'll try